# Regex replacement , pattern matching

Tags: regex, vb.net

Am using the following code

```
  Dim pattern As String = "(a\.? |on\.?)"
  dim input as string ="a creation on"
  dim output as String=Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "  ")
```

It will give me the `output` : `creat`

but my expected output was: `creation`, can anyone suggest me how can i achieve the expected output?

Or suggest me that how can i remove stand alone words specified in the pattern from the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a space before `on` in your regex and replace the matched characters with an empty string.

```
Dim pattern As String = "(a\.? | on\.?)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ResultString As String
Try
    ResultString = Regex.Replace(SubjectString, "(^|\s)(a|on|etc)($|\s)", "  ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)
Catch ex As ArgumentException
    'Syntax error in the regular expression
End Try
```